# How do I keep a switch on one RecyclerView item from influencing a switch on another item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a simple alarm app that holds alarm data in a databased generated with Room, and uses a viewmodel to update the `RecyclerView` adapter's list. However, when I check/uncheck the switch on one item in the `RecyclerView` it sometimes causes another item's switch to check/uncheck itself, and I'm not sure why. Any help on what is wrong with my code is appreciated. Here is the java code:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private List<Alarms> mainAlarmsList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private AlarmsAdapter alarmsAdapter;
private AlarmsAdapter.alarmedInterface coolInterface;
private ImageButton imageButton, clearButton;
private AlarmsViewModel alarmsViewModel;
private AlarmManager epicAlarmManager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    epicAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.alarm_button);
    clearButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.clear_alarms_button);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createTimePicker(MainActivity.this);
        }
});
    alarmsViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(AlarmsViewModel.class);

    clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alarmsViewModel.deleteAllAlarms();
        }
    });
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    alarmsAdapter = new AlarmsAdapter(this);
    //alarmsAdapter.setAlarms(alarmsViewModel.getAllAlarms().getValue());
    coolInterface = new AlarmsAdapter.alarmedInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onSwitch(int position, boolean isChecked, CompoundButton compoundButton) {

            Alarms currentAlarm = mainAlarmsList.get(position);
            String concatenatedString;
            if(isChecked){
                currentAlarm.setOffOn(1);
                concatenatedString = currentAlarm.getId() + " is on " + currentAlarm.getOffOn();
                compoundButton.setChecked(true);
            }
            else {
                currentAlarm.setOffOn(0);
                concatenatedString = currentAlarm.getId() + " is off " + currentAlarm.getOffOn();
                compoundButton.setChecked(false);

            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,concatenatedString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new updateAsync(alarmsViewModel).execute(currentAlarm);
        }
    };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(alarmsAdapter);
    alarmsViewModel.getAllAlarms().observe(this, new Observer<List<Alarms>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Alarms> alarms) {
            alarmsAdapter.setAlarms(alarms);
            alarmsAdapter.setAlarmInterfaceInstance(coolInterface);
            alarmsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mainAlarmsList = alarms;

        }
    });
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
}
public void createTimePicker(Context context){
    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hrDay = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;
    final int min = Calendar.MINUTE;
    TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(context, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() 
 {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            Alarms myAlarm = new Alarms(hourOfDay,minute);
            myAlarm.setOffOn(1);
            alarmsViewModel.insertAlarms(myAlarm);
            alarmsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, myAlarm.getHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, myAlarm.getMin());
            alarmTime(myAlarm,calendar);
        }
    }, hrDay,min,true);
    dialog.show();
}
public void alarmTime(Alarms alarms,Calendar calendar){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,
            alarms.getId(),intent,0);
    long hrlong = alarms.getHour();
    long minlong = alarms.getMin();
    epicAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis() ,pendingIntent);
  }
  class updateAsync extends AsyncTask<Alarms,Void,Void>{
    private AlarmsViewModel viewModel;
    updateAsync(AlarmsViewModel alarmsViewModel1){
        viewModel = alarmsViewModel1;
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Alarms... alarms) {
        viewModel.updateAlarms(alarms[0]);
        return null;
    }
}

}
```

Alarms.java

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo;
import androidx.room.Entity;
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;

@Entity(tableName = "Alarms")
public class Alarms {
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int id;
@ColumnInfo(name = "hour")
private int hour;
@ColumnInfo(name = "min")
private int min;
@ColumnInfo(name = "offOn")
private int offOn;

public Alarms(int hour, int min){
    this.hour = hour;
    this.min = min;
    offOn = 1;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setMin(int min) {
    this.min = min;
}

public void setHour(int hour) {
    this.hour = hour;
}

public void setOffOn(int offOn) {
    this.offOn = offOn;
}

public int getMin() {
    return min;
}

public int getHour() {
    return hour;
}

public int getOffOn() {
    return offOn;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}
}
```

AlarmsAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class AlarmsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmsAdapter.AlarmsViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<Alarms> alarms;
private alarmedInterface alarmInterfaceInstance;
interface alarmedInterface{
    public void onSwitch(int position, boolean checked, CompoundButton compoundButton);
}
public AlarmsAdapter(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public void setAlarmInterfaceInstance(alarmedInterface alarmInterfaceInstance) {
    this.alarmInterfaceInstance = alarmInterfaceInstance;
}

public void setAlarms(List<Alarms> alarms) {
    this.alarms = alarms;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public AlarmsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    return new AlarmsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AlarmsAdapter.AlarmsViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if(alarms.isEmpty()){
        holder.textView.setText("No alarms");
        return;
    }
    else{
        Alarms myAlarm = alarms.get(position);
    if(myAlarm.getOffOn() == 1){
        holder.aSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }
    else if(myAlarm.getOffOn() == 0){
        holder.aSwitch.setChecked(false);
    }
        String x = alarms.get(position).getHour() + ":" + alarms.get(position).getMin();
        holder.aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                alarmInterfaceInstance.onSwitch(position, isChecked,buttonView);
            }
        });
        holder.textView.setText(x);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(alarms != null) {
        return alarms.size();
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
public class AlarmsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView textView;
    SwitchCompat aSwitch;
    public AlarmsViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        aSwitch = view.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    }
}
}
```

AlarmsViewModel.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;

import java.util.List;

public class AlarmsViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private AlarmsRepository repository;
private LiveData<List<Alarms>> allAlarms;
public AlarmsViewModel(Application application){
    super(application);
    repository = new AlarmsRepository(application.getApplicationContext());
    allAlarms = repository.getAlarmsList();
}
public void deleteAllAlarms(){
    repository.deleteAllAlarms();
}
public void updateAlarms(Alarms alarms){
    repository.updateAlarm(alarms);
}
public void insertAlarms(Alarms alarms){
    repository.insertAlarm(alarms);
}

public LiveData<List<Alarms>> getAllAlarms() {
    return allAlarms;
}
}
```

AlarmdDao.java

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData;
import androidx.room.Dao;
import androidx.room.Delete;
import androidx.room.Insert;
import androidx.room.Query;
import androidx.room.Update;

import java.util.List;

@Dao
public interface AlarmDao {
@Query("Select * From Alarms")
public LiveData<List<Alarms>> getAllAlarms();
@Insert
public void insertAlarm(Alarms alarms);
@Update
public void updateAlarm(Alarms alarms);
@Delete
public void deleteAlarm(Alarms alarms);
@Query("Delete From Alarms")
public void deleteAllAlarms();
}

AlarmsDatabase
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import androidx.room.Database;
import androidx.room.Room;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
@Database(entities = {Alarms.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AlarmsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static AlarmsDatabase alarmsDatabase;
private Context context;
public abstract AlarmDao alarmDao();
public static AlarmsDatabase AlarmsDatabaseBuilder(Context context){
        if(alarmsDatabase == null){
            synchronized (AlarmsDatabase.class){
                if (alarmsDatabase == null){
                    alarmsDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            AlarmsDatabase.class,"AlarmsDatabase").build();
                }
        }
    }
        return alarmsDatabase;
}
}
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
package com.pbaileyapps.android.chatpal;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"You just recieved a toast!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue with JSON objects, in my case a set of data is copied into two different JSON lists that both display differently in a recycle view. One of them displays the original data and the second has modified the data. However the modification appeared on both becuase the copies still linked to the original data behind the scences. I fixed this by making a 'deep copy'. It is possible that your alarm objects are not being deep copied into the list so two or more list elements have the same origin.